systemd-networkd: Start service after network device is up
Based on ubuntu, I built a home router/access point.
Network configuration is done completely with systemd-networkd (NetworkManager is disabled). For the local network I have a bridge (bridge0) that bridges ethernet and wifi. This all works fine execept for dnsmasq. Dnsmasq is started too early and thus fails because it cannot bind to its interface (bridge0 and its primary IP).
I tried to change dnsmasq service to wait for the bridge to be only, but this does not help:
[Unit]
Description=dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
Requires=network.target
Wants=nss-lookup.target
Before=nss-lookup.target
#After=network-online.target
BindTo=sys-devices-virtual-net-bridge0.device
After=sys-devices-virtual-net-bridge0.device

....


I also do not want to "want" network-online.service because to my understanding this waits for all network devices to be connected, so it would wait for a WAN connection successful to be established - that may fail for various reasons.
So, how do I tell dnsmasq.service to wait until bridge0 is configured (=has an manual set IP address).
/etc/systemd/network/bridge.network:
[Match]
Name=bridge0

[Network]
Address=192.168.16.1/24
DNS=192.168.16.1
IPForward=ipv4



Probably you need/want to add bind-dynamic to your dnsmasq conf.

Thanks, I had it set to bind-interfaces, because I wasn't aware of bind-dynamic (its not in the example config). bind-dynamic fits my needs and startup is fine now.
